# Nested resource with column other than :id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a nested resource called `state`, which belongs to a resource called `game`:

```rb
resources :games do
  resources :states
end
```

State has a `turn` column, which is unique *by game*, ie there are many states with the same turn (1, for example), but for game 235, there is only one state with turn = 1.

Nesting resources produces URLs of the form `/games/:game_id/states/:id`, while I want `/games/:game_id/states/:turn`.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Actually, nesting those resources produces URLs of the form `/games/:game_id/states/:id`. Aren't those enough for your needs?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that. However, observe the URL I want: it has _turn_ at the end. I want states to be selected on turn number instead of individual id. So no, these aren't enough for my needs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `State` model, add this method:

```
def to_param
  turn
end
```

Now, in your url paths, all you have to do is pass the game and state objects, like this:

```
game_state_path(@game, @state)
```

Since you defined that to_param, the state's attribute `turn` will be used instead of its `id`.

Now, all you have to do is change the finder method in your controller:

```
find_by_state(params[:id])
```

For more information, check this useful guide on [Friendly URLs](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732).

Comment: Bless you, kind sir. I had forgotten all about that.